How TypeScript structurally defines primitive types?
TypeScript is often referred as a structural typing language, the one whose type checking system takes into account only the (mis)match of the members (properties) of value to the target type.
In this regard, how TypeScript actually and structurally defines the primitive types, such as string or number? Are there interfaces declared that include all the needed properties? (charaAt, concat, and so on for strings. toExponential, valueOf, and so on for numbers)
Still, it's not to easy to me to tell what the structural error prevents assignments in cases like this:
type AB = 'A' | 'B';
const c: AB = 'C'; // Type '"C"' is not assignable to type 'AB'.

What properties does not have 'C' which present on 'A' or 'B'?

Primitive and literal types are considered subtypes of those interfaces. There’s no structure per se that distinguishes them (although you could always imagine a phantom property to distinguish them).  Not every single piece of TS’s type system can be explained purely in terms of structural typing.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what’s missing?

Don't think of structural typing as "types based on members" - instead, think of them as "constraints on values" (in a very abstract sense) - that way the "'C' is not assignable to type A" error makes sense, because type A defines a static constraint on the possible values it can represent, and the value 'C' violates that constraint.

@jcalz do you mean here interfaces such as String?

@Dai I got the idea but to me it rather refers to the language of sets than structure: 'C' is not member of the set 'A' | 'B', so it can't be assigned to a variable of type AB. Does it mean that the structural typing is not applicable in the primitive type world?

@IlyaLoskutov Please explain what you mean by "primitive type world" here

@Dai in the ts playground example referred to in my question there is an example when a ball is assigned to a sphere providing that their types has the only and the same property of diameter. It's my understanding of structural typing. On the other hand, 'C' can have all the properties of 'A' or 'B' but still be inassignable to type AB = 'A' | 'B'. Doesn't here the literal value matter, not structure?

@IlyaLoskutov Your understanding of TypeScript's implementation of structural-typing is incomplete then, because TS's types can express more kinds of constraints than just "object must have this property": it can express constraints on values too (such as type C = 'A' | 'B' and type X = 1 | 2 | 3 -  and more besides, for example, any predicate function can be employed as a type via a type-guard (function t( x: unknown ): x is SomeNonTrivialType { ... })

Yes, like String, Number, Boolean, etc. Essentially string is a special subtype of String that has a "primitive"-ness attached to it. And "A" is a special subtype of string that has an "A"-ness attached to it. It's best to think of structural typing as being mostly relevant for objectlike types.  In TS, string is assignable to String but not vice versa, and "A" is assignable to string but not vice versa, and it's not particularly fruitful to think of the "structure" for those. Shall I write up an answer explaining or am I still missing something?

@jcalz I thought String was an alias for string - not a supertype?

@Dai no, you can test it yourself

@jcalz it seems I get the main point that "primitive"-ness (string-ness, 'A'-ness) is something that not related to type structure beyound their corresponding sypertypes (String, Number, etc). Thank you for clarification.

Structural typing is only really applicable to comparing objects or object-like types.  Or at least the part where you compare the structures or shapes of the two types. It is almost a truism that such comparisons would need to "bottom out" somewhere, or else you might be able to conclude that almost every pair of types share a structure (e.g., if "a" and "b" had the same structure due to both being strings, then {a: Date} and {b: Date} would have the same structure since the keys "a" and "b" are the same, and very quickly you end up concluding that large swaths of the type landscape are actually one type).
Comparing shapes of two types is inherently a recursive procedure, and for that to terminate you need some base cases. Primitives serve as such base cases. These base cases are closer to nominal typing than structural typing.  Two nominal types are considered distinct if they were declared in different places.

Non-nullish primitives in TypeScript are considered subtypes of the interfaces corresponding to their auto-boxed wrapper objects.  These interfaces have the methods and properties you associate with primitives, such as toUpperCase() for String and toFixed() for Number.  These primitives are proper subtypes of their wrapper types, meaning that, for example, string (the primitive type) is considered assignable to String (the wrapper object type) but not vice versa:
declare let s: string;
declare let S: String;
S = s; // okay
s = S; // error

Furthermore, literal types are proper subtypes of their associated primitive types. For example, "a" is considered assignable to string but not vice versa:
declare let a: "a";
declare let s: string;
s = a; // okay
a = s; // error

This adds a bit of depth to the type hierarchy, so that "a" would be assignable to {length: number} because "a" is assignable to string which is assignable to String which is structurally assignable to {length: number}:
let lengthable: { length: number } = a; // okay

So you can indeed compare the structure of primitives to other types, but structure alone doesn't account for the differences in types.

If it helps to think purely in terms of structure, you could always do this by imagining that types have "phantom" properties that distinguish them. You could think that string looks like String & {[str]: true} where str is some unique symbol. Indeed, such a technique is actually used in practice to emulate nominal typing; see Intersection of primitive and object types with Typescript.
Playground link to code
